# use of the verb 'come out' regarding photos

Tags: meaning-in-context

Read the following sentences

1. My photos don't come out well.
2. I dont come out well in photos / pictures.

My understanding about the above sentences is

When i say the first sentence it means -

The photos which I click do not come out well. (means i am not a good photographer)

When i say the second sentence it means -

I do not look good in photos / pictures.

Can you confirm if i have got the correct understanding of the sentences or there is anything about it that i should know ?

Thanks

Comment: Correct. 1) Not a good photographer  2) not a photogenic subject.

Comment: Is this question actually about the meaning of ***to come out well***, or is it a matter of whether ***my photo*** means *a photo depicting me* or *a photo taken by me*?

Comment: no its regarding photos. It's not about the meaning of to come out well.

Answer (score 2):

My photos don't come out well.
I don't come out well in photos or pictures.

You are right that the photographs taken by you are not very clear (or their result is not good)  because you aren't good at photography or your camera isn't so good.

You don't come out well in photos means that you are not photogenic or you look less attractive in photos than you are in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Here 'come out' is actually a verbal phrase, 'My photos' is determiner. 'Well' is an adverb. In first sentence, you determined the picture you take usually photos usually don't come well. In the second sentence, you meant to say you don't look well in the pictures taken of you.

Comment: "Well" is an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: Wow! I'm so confused with adverb and adjectives